# Latest Typescript version breaking change with Node.attributes

Tags: xml, typescript, dom

I have some old Typescript code that traverses thru XML documents. In various places it reads Nodes and their attributes, like this:

```
var attribs = node.attributes;
```

With the latest version of TS (2.8.1) i am seeing this as one of the many breaking changes. Why was this attributes property excluded, and what can be the workaround?

My current workaround is this:

```
var attribs = node['attributes'];
```

Comment: Vote to close this. I'll just keep posting.

Answer (score 3):

Attributes do not exist on [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) class, they exists on the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). Therefore you should change your types to use types that work with `Element` (i.e. `HTMLCollection` ..)

```
    const div = document.createElement('div') as any;

    const divA = div as Element;
    const attributes = divA.attributes; // ok

    const divB = divB as Node;
    divB.attributes; // not ok
```